# Save file inside Documents/Downloads react-native

Tags: react-native, pdf, storage, react-native-fs

Is it possible to save files with react-native inside Documents or Downloads?
I am trying to save a pdf file with react-native-fs:

```
let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options)
const destinationPath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/" + fileName + ".pdf"
RNFS.copyFile(file.filePath, destinationPath)
```

but it is saved in the root directory (**/data/user/0/com.prodhealth.mobile.Dev/files/TestTest_2022-02-22_2022-02-22.pdf**) which is not accessible for normal users.

Is there a way to save it directly in Documents/Downloads of internal storage of the phone? I need that user can easily access this file.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#cpsrcstring-deststringpromise)

- cp(src:string, dest:string):Promise

> `dirs` This constant is a hash map containing commonly used folders:

- DocumentDir
- MainBundleDir (Can be used to access files embedded on iOS apps only)
- DownloadDir (Android Only)

Example

```js
RNFetchBlob.fs.cp(SRC_PATH, DEST_PATH)
.then(() => { ... })
.catch(() => { ... })
```

Comment: It is still writing to root dir when i use DocumentDir: "/data/user/0/com.packagename.mobile.Dev/files"

Comment: @user2994290 You can use the download path for Android and the bundle path for iOS.

Comment: for the android download path working, but for the iOS bundle path does not work, I still can not see the file on the device. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. It's working for me.

```
        let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
        const destinationPath = RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath;
        const FileName = 'filename.pdf';

        const destinationFile = destinationPath + "/" + FileName;
        
        RNFS.copyFile(file.filePath, destinationFile)
            .then(result => {
                
                // Delete a file on the project path using RNFS.unlink
                return RNFS.unlink(file.filePath)
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log('FILE DELETED');
                    })
                    // `unlink` will throw an error, if the item to unlink does not exist
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err.message);
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('err', err);
            });
```